# Delete a list item using JSLink

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I need to delete a custom list item using the JSLink. Also, need to show a confirmation message before doing the action. How can I do that ? I have added an Edit link (A tag) for this. How do I do that action on the click of that link ?

Comment: This is not a matter of JSLink, it is related to how you can delete an item with Javascript Client object model!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185011(v=office.14).aspx It is just a matter of you saving the information you need to delete the item from ctx, on render, in your link. Then call a javascript method on click

Comment: CSR is intended for customizing list view and form rendering. So, it is strongly recommended not to follow this way

Comment: @VadimGremyachev I have built nice functionality for updating list items with the help of JSLink on a field and an ashx handler, really nice and user friendly. Not so sure about how nice it will be to delete items though!